# vue3 web components refused to apply inline style due to CSP

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, vite, custom-element

I created a web component with a .ce.vue extension (as described here: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue), so that my styles are inlined in the shadow dom. When I use that web component in a thymeleaf template, I'm getting a CSP error and my styles are not loaded:

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-xxx='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-xxx='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I just build the application and link in a script tag to the generated index.js, then I can use the component, but without any styles

Is there any way to add the styles in a dedicated file (not inline) or to add a nonce value or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is configure the Content Security Policy, as the error is describing. The CSP is defined as a response header, meaning its done server side, where the site administrator can specify what resources the user agent (the browser) can load (or it could be thought of as from "where" and "how" can it load resources).
It seems that however you are serving your site/webapp, it has some default CSP headers defined, which apparently define only two attributes for styles: 'self' and 'nonce=XXX'. This means that you can only load styles from the same origin as the site and that the value of the nonce should also be present on the  definition (if inlined):

```html
<style nonce="JUjuK0D5jHcdLHNTRm2tdR6vj2WqLy">…</style>
```

note that XXX should be equal to this nonce.
the quickest "solution" would be to replace both from the `style-src` directive and `nonce=XXX` with `unsafe-inline`, which as the name suggests is unsafe.
please check the docs for all the available options for the `style-src` directive https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src